# Request for Keyboard Shortcuts in VS CODE

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Could you let me know, how to go the command line with Keyboard instead using my mouse! to Run the code. Also like Duplicating the lines. and any other useful information.

Comment: What kind of other useful information are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To open the terminal:

- Use the **Ctrl+`** keyboard shortcut with the back-tick character.
- You can still open an external shell with the **Ctrl+Shift+C** keyboard shortcut if you prefer to work outside VS Code.
- From the Command Palette **(Ctrl+Shift+P)**, use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

For other useful shortcuts refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf